# Задача на поиск выхода из лабиринта

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Это не совсем классическая задача на нахождение выхода из лабиринта. Она намного сложнее (как мне кажется). Если кто знает алгоритм к данной задаче, то напишите его, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

**Собственно, сама задача**

Таблица размера N × M определяет некоторый лабиринт (нумерация строк и столбцов таблицы начинается с 1). B таблице ячейка с числом 1, обозначает стену, а с числом 0 — свободное место. В первой строке таблицы определяются входы xi, а в последней выходы — yi, i = 1, …, k, которые должны содержать нули. (Но не каждая ячейка с нулём в первой (последней) строке является входом (выходом).) У каждого входа стоит один человек c номером i. Необходимо определить, какое максимальное число людей можно провести по лабиринту, чтобы каждое свободное место лабиринта посещалось не более одного раза, учитывая, что через один выход могут выйти несколько человек. Движение в лабиринте осуществляется только по вертикали или горизонтали.

**Формат входного файла:**
В первой строке находятся три числа: N, M и k.
Во второй строке находятся числа xi для i = 1, …, k, которые соответствуют номерам столбцов первой строки таблицы лабиринта, являющимся входами для i-го человека (первый столбец имеет номер 1).
В третьей строке находятся числа yi для i = 1, …, k, которые соответствуют номерам столбцов последней строки таблицы лабиринта, являющимся выходами.

В следующих N строках задаются строки таблицы лабиринта: 0 — свободное место, 1 — стена.

Входной файл

5 7 4

1 2 6 7

1 5 6 7

0 0 1 0 0 0 0

1 1 0 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 1 0 0 0

**Формат выходного файла:**
В первой строке выведите максимальное число людей, которое удалось провести.
В следующих N строках выведите по M элементов в каждой — таблицу лабиринта, содержащую пути людей, которых удалось провести: позиции лабиринта, по которым должен идти к выходу человек с номером i помечается числом i + 1 (так как через один выход могут выйти несколько человек, то позиция выхода помечается номером (i + 1) последнего человека (i), который через неё вышел).

Выходной файл

1

0 0 1 4 4 4 0

1 1 0 4 0 0 1

1 1 1 4 0 0 0

4 4 4 4 0 0 0

4 0 1 1 0 0 0

**Я попробовал решить данную задачу, используя волновой алгоритм поиска, однако практика показала, что во многих случаях данный алгоритм не работает, т.к. кратчайший путь не всегда самый оптимальный. Есть ситуации, когда путь одного человека, отрезает пути другим людям, которые по факту могли бы найти выход из лабиринта**

Comment: Почему в примере решения выводят 1 человека, если можно больше?

Comment: Условие абсолютно корректное. Читайте внимательнее, там все прозрачно. Если мы идем с 6 позиции, 7 позиция будет закрыта. Если идем с 7 позиции - 6 закрыта. Правда, оптимальных путей может быть несколько. Можно выбрать любой (необязательно такой, как в примере)

Comment: `Читайте внимательнее, там все прозрачно. Если мы идем с 6 позиции, 7 позиция будет закрыта. Если идем с 7 позиции - 6 закрыта.` - какая здесь логика, где об этом в условии написано?

Comment: Вот тут. "Необходимо определить, какое максимальное число людей можно провести по лабиринту, чтобы каждое свободное место лабиринта посещалось не более одного раза, учитывая, что через один выход могут выйти несколько человек."